# JPA/Hibernate ManyToOne Association always null

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities `BookingLegEntity` and `BookingEntity` which reference each other. But anytime I try to retrieve them from the database (e.g. via findByUuid), `BookingLegEntity.belongsTo` remains null.

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKING_LEG")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE BOOKING_LEG SET deleted = true WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class BookingLegEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BELONGS_TO")
    private BookingEntity belongsTo;

    // .. 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DISTRIBUTOR")
    private DistributorEntity distributor;

    @Column(name = "TRANSPORT_TYPE")
    @Convert(converter = TripTypeEnumConverter.class)
    private TripTypeEnum transportType;

    // ... 

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOKINGS")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE BOOKINGS SET deleted = true WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class BookingEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", unique=true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="BOOKING_ID")
    @Convert(converter = BookingIdConverter.class)
    private BookingId bookingId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="BOOKED_BY")
    private UserEntity bookedBy;

    // ..

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "belongsTo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<BookingLegEntity> bookingLegs = new HashSet<>();

    // ... 

}
```

Here is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface BookingLegRepository extends JpaRepository<BookingLegEntity, Long> {

    Optional<BookingLegEntity> findByUuid(UUID id);

    // ... 

}
```

The values in the database itself look correct:

[image]
[image]

What is really strange is that this has worked before (belongsTo was not null) but suddenly stopped working. Does anyone has any idea as to what we might do wrong here?

Comment: You should not use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on `@ManyToOne`, because removing one BookingLeg will cause to remove the whole Booking, try to remove this cascade

Comment: We are never deleting BookingLegEntities or BookingEntities, but I guess you are right. I could change that.

Comment: 'What is really strange is that this has worked before (belongsTo was not null) but suddenly stopped working' - how about a `git bisect` then?

Comment: Since you use `@Where(clause = "deleted=false")`, are you sure that the `BookingEntity` is not deleted?

Comment: Yes, they are not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `cascade = CASCADEType.ALL` on your `ManyToOne` annotation, because removing one `BookingLeg` will cause a removal of all in corresponding `Booking`

The solution should be to use
`cascade = CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})` in its stead.

I would `Truncate Cascade` or `Delete from Bookings where original_itinerary is null` before i move on to using the new entities.

Sincerely hope it helps. (No hate if it doesn't pls)

Edit  : i didnt see that comment by @dey, its my own. :P saw his comment after posting my ans

Comment: Soryr, but this does not answer the question at all. I am not concerned about the delte-cascade (since we never delete those entities anyway).